# Experimental curve fitting

Tags: r, python, nonlinear-regression

I am doing a study project in data science.

I have a number of experimental curves like the one shown below.

[image]

I assume the curve can be described with an equation like this:

[image]

So I need to find constants qi (initial value), b and Di. My first question: is there a library in Python or R (preferably Python) to find the constants?

One option is to transform the variables so that the relationship is linear but different equations can work in different cases, so it would be best to have a universal method.

After that I want to test the null hypothesis that the experimental data belong to a distribution described by this equation because other equations may apply and rogue cases can exist with erratic behavior. I want to use Wilcoxon rank-sum test. My second question: is this the right approach?

Comment: Your best bet is probably *nonlinear least squares*. R: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nls.html python: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html

Comment: $John, thank you! I see that R has ANOVA and other nice features.